# Speeding up Stanford Dependency Parses in Python

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

Is there a faster way to implement the `CoreNLPParser` or **should I interact with the API through another library?** Or should I dust off the Java books?

I have a corpus of 6500 sentences that I'm running through the `CoreNLPParser` method in `nltk.parse.corenlp`. I have isolated everything else I'm doing from my main project to test the `tree_height` function I wrote previously. However, the speed is the same--in fact, this process takes more than 15 minutes to complete.

Here's my `tree_height` function:

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
Parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000')
def tree_height(tokenized_sent):
    ddep = Parser.raw_parse(tokenized_sent)
    for i in ddep:
        sent_height = i.height()
    return sent_height
```

I am parsing Spanish sentences and have previously started the CoreNLP server using the following command:

`java -mx10g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties  -port 9000 -timeout 15000`

I have also played with changing the `mx3g` part to `mx5g`, which doesn't seem to make a much of a difference.

I've seen [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1390) and am running a recent version of StanfordCoreNLP.

**--- Update ---**

I was concerned that the reason my script was performing slowly was because of inefficiencies or poorly written code--so here is what I've tried to do to find the inefficiencies with my code:

1. Iterating over all the data (from a pandas dataframe) **without calling any NLP functions** takes about 20 seconds.
2. Iterating over all the data and **only** sentence tokenizing all the data takes ~30 seconds
3. In my latest attempt I added all the tokenized sentences to a variable and iteratively called the `tree_height` function on each one and **found no difference in the speed** (taking as long as before I started isolating code).

Comment: From my personal experience there is little you can do with the Stanford CoreNLPParser  speed but resorting to another solution (that scales better).

One quick hack is to pass text in batches. However I wonder how fast(er) that is going to be in your case.

Comment: Could you share the file you're trying to annotate? I think it was pretty fast when I tried parsing another data.

Comment: I'm trying to write up some info on accessing the server via Python.  Your time should not be that slow, when I parsed Spanish sentences via the server it only took ~2 minutes to do 6500.  I'll write more soon.

Comment: @alvas You're my NLP hero. I am not allowed to share the file, I've updated the question with some things I have tried since I posted.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp I think it would be useful to see how you would set this up--I wonder if maybe there's something about my StanfordNLP setup that I might be missing or have forgotten to do.

Comment: I'll try to post an answer today...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here is a description of a Python interface we are developing.  To get the latest version you'll have to download from GitHub and follow the install instructions (which are easy to follow !!)

**Go to GitHub and clone the Python interface repo:**

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp

**cd into the directory and type** `python setup.py install`

(soon we'll set this up with `conda` and `pip` etc..., but for now it's still under development...you can get an older version on pip right now)

**in a separate terminal window, start up a Java server:**

```
java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

NOTE: make sure to have all of the necessary jars in your `CLASSPATH` or run with the `-cp "*"` option from a directory with all of the appropriate jars.

**run this Python code:**

```
import corenlp
client = corenlp.CoreNLPClient(start_server=False, annotators=["tokenize", "ssplit", "pos", "depparse"])
# there are other options for "output_format" such as "json"
# "conllu", "xml" and "serialized"
ann = client.annotate(u"...", output_format="text")
```

`ann` will contain the final annotated info (including the dependency parse)...this should be dramatically faster than what you are reporting...please try it out and let me know.

Comment: That is dramatically faster!! I just need to figure out how to find the tree height of a given sentence now--`NLTK` returns a `Tree` class--which has a handy `height()` method. Off the top of your head, is there a super fast way to do this?

Comment: BTW -- The command you gave me to start the server didn't work, so I used the one I listed in my question and everything ran great.

Comment: Sorry I guess in my set up I have the spanish jars  in my CLASSPATH..did it not work because it couldn't find that file?

Answer (score 0):

Since parsing natural language can be complex, the experience that you had seems unexeptional. When you try to parse a simple sentence with spanishPCFG.ser.gz model in Stanford Parser Demo Interface http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp it may take some miliseconds, however a long and complex sentence might take some seconds. You may give it a try, they supply statistics as well.

If you need to save time, you may try to parallelize your parsing task; that is all I can suggest.

The link that you supplied is a discussion on taggers that Steven Bird says it is resolved, by the way.

Cheers